# "TypeError: events.map is not a function" I am gettting this error when ever I am creating a new event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, react-router

events.jsx

```
export default function Event({eventForm,setEventForm}) {
    const[data,setData]=useState(sampleData);
    function HandleCreateEvent(event) {
        setData(...data,event)
    }
    return(
    <Fragment>
     <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
            <EventList events={data}/>
         </Grid.Column>
         <Grid.Column width={6}>
           {
               eventForm &&
               <EventForm setEventForm={setEventForm} setData={setData} createEvent={HandleCreateEvent}/>
           };
            
         </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
    </Fragment>);
}
```

eventlist.jsx

```
 export default function EventList({events}){
     return(
        <Fragment>
        
        {events.map(event=>
            <EventListItem key={event.id} event={event}/>
        )}
        </Fragment>
    );    
  }
```

EventForm.jsx

```
export default function EventForm({setEventForm ,setData, createEvent})
{

const initialValues=
{
    title:'',
    company:'',
    description:'',
    city:'',
    venue:'',
    date:''
}

const[values,setValues]=useState(initialValues);
function handleFormSubmit()
{
    createEvent({...values,id:cuid(), hostedBy:"bob", attendees:[], hostPhotoURL:"/assets/default.png"});
    setEventForm(false);
}
function handleInputSubmit(e)
{
    const{name,value}=e.target
    setValues({...values,[name]:value});   
}
```

From eventform.jsx I am passing the data in JSON format and accepting it in event.jsx and then reverting it in Eventlist.jsx but in eventList.jsx it is showing the error. I am creating the event in this function.

Comment: well i dont have any problem in my props

Comment: https://github.com/Alphonse-03/events-manager   this is the link can you please go through it

Comment: Here you have an error setData(...data,event), If you are trying to add new event, should be setData([...data,event]). You are getting the error because you are using the comma operator, in this case events will be equal to the last operand(event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working App: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-breeze-vsx5y?file=/src/features/Event/Event.jsx:0-793)

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Grid } from "semantic-ui-react";
import EventForm from "./EventForm";
import EventList from "./EventList";
import { sampleData } from "./eventData";
export default function Event({ eventForm, setEventForm }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(sampleData);
  function HandleCreateEvent(event) {
    //set state like this 
    setData([...data, event]);
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
          <EventList events={data} />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={6}>
          {eventForm && (
            <EventForm
              setEventForm={setEventForm}
              createEvent={HandleCreateEvent}
            />
          )}
          ;
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: well that worked thanks a lot Ketan  can you please explain me why you have used those set of brackets??

Comment: what it does is, it takes the elements of our previous state, i.e. ```data```, unpacks it and stores it in the new array, and the new element ```event``` is appended to the previous ```data``` elements. it's like concat operation.

Comment: can we say this that for every JSON kind of data we need a square bracket to destructure it